# Update query not updating values in the table using Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am trying to run a simple update query which should obtain a value from a form and update an already existing table. This is done using VBA. On executing no error message is shown but the table isn't updated with the new value from NI. The code is as follows.

```
   strsql = "UPDATE t_datefromform SET "
   strsql = strsql & "[txtmonth] = '" & [Forms]![SupplierScorecard].[txtMonth] & "'"

   Debug.Print strsql

   CurrentDb.Execute strsql
```

Comment: Please show us the output of Debug.Print!

Comment: After showing us the output of Debug.Print, please let us know if the same SQL string works well outside of VBA -- in other words, as the basis for a query object which is run "manually", from the query design interface.

Comment: The output of the Debug.Print statement is UPDATE t_datefromform SET [txtmonth] = 'Oct-2012'

Comment: The SQL string doesn't work outside of VBA also i.e when run manually

Comment: And what data type is [txtmonth]?

Comment: Seems ok to me at first glance. How many rows are in the table?

Comment: It will just have one row. Its a dynamic table which will delete the existing row of the table and updates it with the new value obtained from the combobox.

Comment: So, you need to work on fixing the update with the simple version -- `UPDATE t_datefromform SET [txtmonth] = 'Oct-2012'`.  Make sure there is a semi-colon (`;`) at the end of the string; this is generally required for all SQL in MS Access.  If still no success, then please show us the content of that table that has only record.

Comment: The semi-colon isn't required, but good practice. I'm curious about the deleting the OP mentioned.

Comment: Me too!  This seems like a strange procedure.

Answer (score 0):

set [txtmonth] is an input parameter
use
strsql = "Update t_datefromform set txtmonth = '" & [Forms]![SupplierScorecard].[txtMonth] & "'"